# How can i do that in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

[My picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkcII.png) 
About my issue. Please help me! Thank you very must.

Comment: This is not how StackOverflow works. Please read the FAQs and ask a proper quesiton

Comment: sorry. because i'm vietnamese.. this is my first question

Comment: What's the question (*you never stated it*)? What have you done so far? Have you tried using JS libraries for slideshows? Also see: [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you're going to get a good answer give the vagueness of your question, but I'll give you a start. For one, you could use one of several good sliders that exist. For a start, I'll recommend three that I really like: [Slidr](https://github.com/bchanx/slidr), [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), and [Flickity](http://flickity.metafizzy.co/).

The second option is that you could build a custom slider of sorts. Now, given the way you've asked the question, I am going to assume you don't want to do this. Nonetheless, you could stack all of the slides on top of each other and use CSS transforms to slide them in from different directions simply using `translateX()`, and triggering these animations using event listeners on `click`. This is obviously a very stripped down explanation, but is essentially what a very simple slider like Slidr does.

Comment: Thank you very must